# How to create a new DFS folder without any targets using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I'm trying to create a folder hierarchy for my projects using Powershell. The main project folder will not be connected to a target. The subfolders will be connected to targets on four different servers.

```
\\domain\production (namespace)
-projects

--000p_company_dfs_test01 (no target)
---comp (with target)
---images (with target)
---admin (with target)

--001p_company_dfs_test02 (no target)
---comp (with target)
---images (with target)
---admin (with target)
```

I'm having no trouble defining the hierarchies using the DFS Management window, but I can't get my head around what command I need to use to create the targetless project folders.

I have tried using New-DfsnFolder, but this command need a target-argument:

```
New-DfsnFolder -Path ("\\domain\production\projects\" +$project +"\")
```

I have also tried to add the folder using the following command:

```
New-Item -ItemType "directory" -Path ("\\domain\production\projects\" +$project +"\")
```

The command return: "Access to the path '001p_company_dfs_test02' is denied"

Powershell version:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
3      0      -1     -1
```

Any suggestions?

Best,
Lars Erik

Comment: There is two ways to do this: --------------------DFSUtil Link Add "DFSUtil Link Add "\\domain\production\projects\001p_company_dfs_test02\images" "\\server1\projects\001p_company_dfs_test02\images"-------------And:-----------New-DfsnFolderTarget -Path \\domain\production\projects\001p_company_dfs_test02\images -TargetPath \\domain\production\projects\001p_company_dfs_test02\images

Answer (score 1):

The solution was surprisingly simple. Create the subfolders with targets and the parent folder will be generated automatically. There is two ways to do this:

```
DFSUtil Link Add "DFSUtil Link Add "\\domain\production\projects\001p_company_dfs_test02\images" "\\server1\projects\001p_company_dfs_test02\images"
```

Or:

```
Ne‌​w-DfsnFolderTarget -Path \\domain\production\projects\001p_company_dfs_test02\images -TargetPath \\domain\production\projects\001p_company_dfs_test02\images
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Ne‌​w-DfsnFolderTarget -Path \\domain\production\projects\001p_company_dfs_test02\images -TargetPath \\domain\production\projects\001p_company_dfs_test02\images
```

is not the same as what is pictured below. 
[dfs pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMpSi.jpg)